# Can we create a AWS Glue Crawler in such a way that input file is csv but data catalog is in parquet format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet

What I want is glue crawler will take the raw csv file as a input and it will create a data catalog in parquet directly without etl job ! is it possible?

I received so many mixed responses. I wanted to know if this is possible? May be AWS got latest update or something?

I tried Amazon Q and it says, the gle crawler by default will create a data catalog in parquet format. I tried to find this option in aws console. But, I think using AWS CLI can we specify that….

I want a glue crawler will take the raw csv file as a input and it will create a data catalog in parquet directly without etl job ! is it possible?

Comment: Generally, crawler will crawl the folders or files in S3 buckets and defines schema from them and then it creates tables in data catalog which can be queried using Athena. If you want to convert input CSV file to parquet file, you can use AWS Glue job to read CSV file and write it back as parquet file. In the glue job itself you can use glue crawlers to crawl output parquet file which will create data catalog table.